# What is the difference between chan and san and sempai?

Tags: honorifics

What is the difference between chan and san and sempai?

Answer (score 2):

**San** title of respect typically used between equals of any age.

**Chan** it expresses that the speaker finds a person endearing. It comes from a "cute" pronouncing of -san (in Japanese, replacing s sounds with ch sounds is seen as cute). In general, chan is used for babies, young children, grandparents and teenagers.

**Sempai** is used to address or refer to one's senior colleagues (respected colleagues) in a school, dojo, or sports club. So at school, the students in higher grades than oneself are senpai.

crédit : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_honorifics#Senpai_and_k.C5.8Dhai